# Uploading to Mac Store via XCode - Multiple binaries share the same codesign path - Unity 2021.3

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, upload, agora.io

I have integrated the Agora Video SDK into my project.
Now I'm trying to upload(update to new version) it to Mac Store via XCode.
And I got the error in the picture below. I have tried to remove and install the SDK.
I'm really getting frustrated with this issue...
I use Unity 2021.3.0f1

Hope you will understand and help me :)

Thank you all!

[XCode Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV7uq.jpg)

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I think this is an issue with Agora SDK. Hope they will solve it soon...